# Automatically Print webpage with PHP

Tags: php, python, printing, web

I have a php script that takes an invoice number and generates a PDF invoice with all relevant information, when the script has finished the PDF is then displayed on the screen in the users browser. I am curious to know how I can then automatically print the PDF? I realize that there probably isn't a way with php or javascript because of security/spam issues.

Unfortunately manually printing the page is not really an option because the users currently have two printers, in the current Access based system one invoice is sent to the colour and two invoices are sent to the black and white printer. This is all done automatically, but now due to certain circumstances I would like to use PHP as a large part of the system is PHP based already.

I have thought about using a Linux based machine and trying to use a python webserver to get the PDF and print it, but I have no idea what this would require or how to do it. Any feedback would be great!

Answer (score 1):

IMO your best option, given what you've said, is going to be to use Linux to print it.

```
wget http://1.2.3.4/invoice.pdf
pdf2ps invoice.pdf invoice.ps
lpr -Pcolor invoice.ps
lpr -Pbw -#2 invoice.ps
```

Something like that, perhaps, should work.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go as well, thanks @DimeCadmium, I will try this option. I believe this code is perfect but will ideally search a folder because the invoice url will be different each time.

Comment: You can also use for example `wget -O invoice.pdf http://1.2.4.5/invoice.php?id=1234`, to save it to a different name. Or, if pdf2ps accepts STDIN (I'm not sure), you could pipe it: `wget -O - http://blabla/bla | pdf2ps - invoice.ps`

Comment: +1, Sounds like a good solution. It definitely sounds like the "user" could just be a cron-job!

Answer (score 0):

you can do with vbscript try this

```
<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>
              <form>
              Printing webpage without prompt window. As of now it's possible with VBScript(IE).
              <br/>
              <button onclick="Print()">Print Now</button>
              <br/>

              </form>
              <script language="VBScript">
                Sub Print()
                  OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
                  OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
                  OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
                  If DA Then
                    call WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
                  Else
                    call WebBrowser1.IOleCommandTarget.Exec _
                        (OLECMDID_PRINT ,OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,"","","")
                  End If
                End Sub
              </script>
```

Comment: Well the PHP actually turns the html into a PDF file you see, which I require because the file will be printed but also saved and used for emailing etc so PDF is ideal. I can use the Print(); function in Javascript but that just opens the dialog and doesnt print automatically.

Comment: This looks very interesting but doesn't seem to be working, possibly my fault but do I need to install anything or set anything?

Comment: try to open it up on IE and active the activex when it asks... if it does not clean your browser data!

Comment: Only works in IE and if activex is enabled in most business environments neither are possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

php pdf library available

http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php

http://sanjoyinfoworld.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-generate-pdf-in-php.html

refere this sites

Comment: Hi @rajesh57 I already have a way to generate the PDF thank you, what I'm looking for is a way to print the webpage/PDF automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code on java script

```
<A HREF="javascript:window.print()">Click to Print This Page</A>


 You can set it to print off of an image:
   <A HREF="javascript:window.print()">
  <IMG SRC="print_image.gif" BORDER="0"</A>

  And yes, you can set it to trigger off a button:
<FORM>
 <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="window.print()">
  </FORM>
```

you can't getting any idea view this sites

```
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-  Using-JavaScript.htm
```